# Cсылка на телеграм канал обход блокировки без использования сервисов

Tags: telegram

Существует множество сервисов, которые предоставляют такую услугу. Может кто в курсе, как обойти блокировку t.me? сервисы же как то заставляют изменённую ссылку работать, открывать Telegram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем ответ очень прост:

```
<a href="tg://resolve?domain=<mytelegramchanel>" title="Telegram">Мой канал</a>
```

где  ссылка на ваш канал, естественно без знаков "<" и ">".

Главное чтобы Телеграм был установлен у клиента.

Answer (score 0):

Я не призываю вас пренебрегать блокировкой web ресурсов. Но в познавательных целях поведаю вам что прокси, vpn и прочите протоколы шифрующие ваш трафик и пропускающий его из других стран позволяет заходить на заблокированные сайты. К тому же блокировка производится через провайдера, таким образом на одном провайдере на сайт будет невозможно зайти а на другом проблем с этим не возникнет.

Comment: Не является ответом как таковым, нет конкретики, хоть и есть упоминания про прокси и впн, но на ответ не тянет.

Comment: Мне поделиться ссылками на VPN или рассказать как трафик пропустить через тор? Я ответил на вопрос более чем, я не призываю человека к использованию сервисов о которых я написал, но каким образом и с помощью каких технологий это можно сделать написал. Как регистрироваться и выбрать сервер VPN будет излишне. Вы можете дать свой ответ который будет правильным на ваш взгляд и если не устраивает мой ответ то нажмите на стрелочку вниз =)

Comment: Я может не так изъяснился, мне надо разместить ссылку на сайте на канал телеграм, но не хочется использовать сервисы, это вообще возможно?

Comment: безусловно, вы можете использовать прямую ссылку на канал, обойти ограничения телеграм со стороны другого пользователя у вас не получится. Чтоб вы понимали, ссылка которая открывает  ваше приложение телеграм зависит от сервиса ( протокола ) открываемого приложением. Все сервисы которые обходят прямую ссылку позволяют вам передать ее приложению из браузера на не заблокированном сайте ( рассчитывая что само приложение у вас работает через прокси )

Comment: Вы можете переформулировать ваш вопрос чтоб я мог откорректировать свой ответ.